# Verify that all edges in a 2D graph are sufficiently far from each other

Tags: graph, gis, closest-points

I have a graph where each node has coordinates in 2D (it's actually a geographic graph, with latitude and longitude.)
I need to verify that if the distance between two edges is less than MAX_DIST then they share a node. Of course, if they intersect, then the distance between them is zero.

The brute force algorithm is trivial, is there a more efficient algorithm?

I was thinking of trying to adapt https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem to graph edges (and ignoring pairs of edges with a shared node), but it is not trivial to do so.

Comment: How about adding all edges to a [Rtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) index; afterwards you would only need to check the closest edges for MAX_DIST instead of all of them.

Comment: I don't know how an Rtree with all the edges would help me find the closest edges

Comment: After creating the index you can use functions like `get_nearest_objects(bbox)` which is a lot faster than manually checking all other edges; think of it like a regular index you use when working with a database. I can try to run some tests if you can provide some test data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curios to see how the rtree index idea would perform so I created a small script to test it using two really cool libraries for Python: [Rtree](https://toblerity.org/rtree/index.html) and [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
The snippet generates **1000** segments with **1 < length < 5** and coordinates in the **[0, 100]** interval, populates the **index** and then counts the pairs that are closer than **MAX_DIST==0.1** (using the classic and the index-based method).
In my tests the index method was around **25x** faster using the conditions above; this might vary greatly for your data set but the result is encouraging:

```
found 532 pairs of close segments using classic method
7.47 seconds for classic count
found 532 pairs of close segments using index method
0.28 seconds for index count
```

The performance and correctness of the index method depends on how your segments are distributed (how many are close, if you have very long segments, the parameters used).

```py
import time
import random
from rtree import Rtree
from shapely.geometry import LineString


def generate_segments(number):
    segments = {}
    for i in range(number):
        while True:
            x1 = random.randint(0, 100)
            y1 = random.randint(0, 100)
            x2 = random.randint(0, 100)
            y2 = random.randint(0, 100)
            segment = LineString([(x1, y1), (x2, y2)])
            if 1 < segment.length < 5:  # only add relatively small segments
                segments[i] = segment
                break
    return segments


def populate_index(segments):
    idx = Rtree()
    for index, segment in segments.items():
        idx.add(index, segment.bounds)
    return idx


def count_close_segments(segments, max_distance):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(segments)-1):
        s1 = segments[i]
        for j in range(i+1, len(segments)):
            s2 = segments[j]
            if s1.distance(s2) < max_distance:
                count += 1
    return count


def count_close_segments_index(segments, idx, max_distance):
    count = 0
    for index, segment in segments.items():
        close_indexes = idx.nearest(segment.bounds, 10)
        for close_index in close_indexes:
            if index >= close_index:  # do not count duplicates
                continue
            close_segment = segments[close_index]
            if segment.distance(close_segment) < max_distance:
                count += 1
    return count


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MAX_DIST = 0.1
    s = generate_segments(1000)
    r_idx = populate_index(s)
    t = time.time()
    print("found %d pairs of close segments using classic method" % count_close_segments(s, MAX_DIST))
    print("%.2f seconds for classic count" % (time.time() - t))
    t = time.time()
    print("found %d pairs of close segments using index method" % count_close_segments_index(s, r_idx, MAX_DIST))
    print("%.2f seconds for index count" % (time.time() - t))
```

Comment: Very cool! I actually figured out how to use rtree to solve this problem, I will review your solution as well, really awesome :)